# How to use a switch statement with Guid?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, switch-statement

In the following C# code, cboRole returns a Guid.

I'm then trying to use it in a switch statement to do some actions.

cboRole can return only 4 different Guid so I think a switch is a good option for me.

The thing is that all the case are ignored and I always get the default action. When I debug I clearly see that cboRole return a value like in the following printscreen.

What is the correct way to "compare" Guids in a C# switch statement

Code:

```
if (!cboRole.IsNull)
{
    switch (cboRole.EditValue.ToStringEx())
        {
            case "532E8EED-9E72-42E0-871E-36470C1AE327":
                param1 = "4E08BA7C-E81F-40AE-92F0-DF33A98DD0BB";
                MessageBox.Show("It's working");
                break;
            case "FA7637E9-A9E4-4D57-A59B-80615424D27F":
                param1 = "E540C382-F22C-4FE2-9068-1E10AA8DD076";
                break;
            case "2734CCD9-93E6-4A86-8B83-5EA9E62FA921":
                param1 = "8A54F8D5-5B74-4B3F-A29A-D423AA8DD02E";
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Not Working");
                break;
        }
```

[image: Debug Print Screen]

Comment: I don't know where you get your ToStringEx() function but a plain ToString() on a guid returns the guid in lowercase.  just use `cboRole.EditValue.ToString().ToUpper()` and you should be good.

Comment: it doesn't matter what `EditValue` is, all that matters is what gets returned by the `ToStringEx()` method.

Comment: also you should consider creating constants with meaningful names and store your GUIDs in them instead of just using them in your switch.
`const string MyGuidValue1 = "532E8EED-9E72-42E0-871E-36470C1AE327";`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your switch statements are in upper-case while your `ToStringEx()` returns the `Guid` in lower-case.

You can use

```
switch (cboRole.EditValue.ToStringEx().ToUpper())
```

or modify your `case` statements.

Comment: +1, `ToString` default implementation for GUID also returns lower case GUID.

Comment: Do you know what `ToStringEx` does? Can you be certain that `ToStringEx` doesn't automatically convert the string to upper case?  Can you be certain that `ToStringEx` doesn't do other things?

Comment: @SamIam It's true that it may do other things, but I think it's fairly reasonable to assume that this is indeed the case (no pun intended). If it's not, I'm sure OP will comment.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to post code in mini-comments but here's what ToStringEx() does: public static string ToStringEx(this object theString)
{
 if (theString == null || theString == DBNull.Value)
 {
  return string.Empty;
 }
 return theString.ToString();
}

Comment: @MartinLebel Enclose your text using \` That should create code as such `Hello, World!`

Answer (score 35):

with c#7 you can now use switch with [Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) for this purpose.

```
switch (cboRole)
{
    case var r when (r == new Guid("532E8EED-9E72-42E0-871E-36470C1AE327")):
        param1 = "4E08BA7C-E81F-40AE-92F0-DF33A98DD0BB";
        MessageBox.Show("It's working");
        break;
    case var r when (r == new Guid("FA7637E9-A9E4-4D57-A59B-80615424D27F")):
        param1 = "E540C382-F22C-4FE2-9068-1E10AA8DD076";
        break;
    case var r when (r == new Guid("2734CCD9-93E6-4A86-8B83-5EA9E62FA921")):
        param1 = "8A54F8D5-5B74-4B3F-A29A-D423AA8DD02E";
        break;
    default:
        MessageBox.Show("Not Working");
        break;
}
```

This also works if you have defined static readonly new Guid"..") variables.

Comment: This is so much better. Also works with T4 templates!!