# Make an switch case that triggers based on Guid

Tags: c#, static, switch-statement, constants

I am working on a switch case that triggers based certain guid is encountered..

Problem is that I can not store the guid without making it static readonly.

How do i resolve this issue?

```
public struct Types
{
    public static readonly Guid Standard = new Guid("{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}");
    public static readonly Guid Morning = new Guid("{22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222}");
}

public string GetStyle(Guid stage)
{
    switch (stage)
    {
        case Types.Standard:
            return "Not normal";
        case Types.Morning:
            return "Not anormal";
        default:
            return "Normal";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `switch` doesn't work with `Guid`, so if you're talking about `static readonly` vs. `const`, there's nothing you can do there. Do you *really* need to use a switch?

Comment: @madreflection for now its just two cases i need to adjust for, but this can easily grow, and therefore i decided to use a switch as it easily scales

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281795/how-to-use-a-switch-statement-with-guid

Comment: @RufusL fixed... :D My mistake tried to make a minimal version, copy paste error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [latest switch syntax (aka "pattern matching")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#pattern-matching) you can achieve that:

```
        public static string GetStyle(Guid stage)
        {
            switch (stage)
            {
                case Guid standard when standard == new Guid("{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}"):
                    return "Not normal";
                case Guid morning when morning == new Guid("{22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222}"):
                    return "Not anormal";
                default:
                    return "Normal";
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can polish, or reformat it in the way you like for sure. Please mark it as the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is to use a `Dictionary<Guid, string>` to map the guids to their string counterparts, and then just return a value from the dictionary if it exist. This alleviates the need for a `switch` statement altogether, and should result in cleaner code.

```
private Dictionary<Guid, string> StyleMap = new Dictionary<Guid, string>
{
    {Types.Standard, "Not normal" },
    {Types.Morning, "Not anormal" },
};

public string GetStyle(Guid stage)
{
    string result;
    return StyleMap.TryGetValue(stage, out result) ? result : "Normal";
}
```

Comment: This seems clean, but also requires the dictionary to be created every time somebody calls the GetStyle Function...

Comment: `return styleMap.TryGetValue(stage, out var result) ? result : "Normal";`  Only truly necessary if the dictionary can change, but I believe it avoids a second search, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: @ane true. I had a comment about that in the answer, but I can't think of a good reason *not* to have it as a field so I modified the answer accordingly. thanks!